# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, packages, input-encodings

I'm writing my graduation project and suddenly it won't compile anymore. I'm getting the following error in the .bbl file: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char − (U+2212)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX`.

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be easier to solve you problem if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, otherwise we'll have to guess... If you search for `Unicode U+2212` in the internet you'll find that it is a kind of "minus sign" (`−`). Try searching for it in your document and replace by the appropriate ascii character. Since you said it's in the .bbl, probably you'll find it in the .bib file, and you probably can replace it by an en-dash (`--`).

Comment: Obriga pelo interesse, depois de muito pesquisar encontrei a reposta aqui mesmo, a solução foi colocar \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-} antes de \begin{document} e o arquivo foi compilado normalmente.

Comment: @JoicySousa Had a similar issue, your advice solved it quickly :).